# Objective-c : addTarget to UIButton not calling

Tags: objective-c, ios, events, uibutton

I tried to use addTarget to add an event to a UIButton like this

```
EGOImageButton* image = [[EGOImageButton alloc] initWithPlaceholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"screen.png"]];
    [image setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbnail]];
    [image setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, self.cellsize, self.cellsize)];
    [image setTag: [self.photoIDs count]-1];
    [image addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:image];
    [image release];
```

The function definition is this:

```
-(void)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"Thumbnail Clicked");
 }
```

This is the code for EGOImageButton init function

```
- (id)initWithPlaceholderImage:(UIImage*)anImage {
return [self initWithPlaceholderImage:anImage delegate:nil];    }

- (id)initWithPlaceholderImage:(UIImage*)anImage delegate:(id<EGOImageButtonDelegate>)aDelegate {
if((self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero])) {
    self.placeholderImage = anImage;
    self.delegate = aDelegate;
    [self setImage:self.placeholderImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

return self;
```

}

Error is looking like this:

> -[**NSCFType buttonTouched:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c804a0
>   2012-06-06 01:36:59.061 Photo Collage for Facebook[2416:16103] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType buttonTouched:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c804a0'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0046a5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01402313 objc_exception_throw + 44
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0046c0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x003db966 __*forwarding*** + 966
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x003db522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50

Comment: what is EGOImageButton? an UIButton?

Comment: Yes it inherited from UIButton. It gave me EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I commented that addTarget line. It work without error. Sometime it gave me unrecognized selector

Comment: where is buttonTouched defined?

Comment: if u import this  EGOImageButton  class then directly use this class method. directly

Comment: I have placed an #import of that file. Otherwise I would have error when i start running the application.

Comment: What does `initWithPlaceholderImage:` look like?

Comment: I show some error message as well.

Comment: I have it working by having the event placed under the class inherited from UIViewController... The event function previously was placed under the class which was inherited from UIView. Do anyone know why it work like that? Now I have the addTarget pointing to other class's function.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit strange it doesn't get called, since it seens to be set up correctly ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968446/cant-able-to-add-click-event-in-uibutton as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968446/cant-able-to-add-click-event-in-uibutton) ). My first guess, without actually have access to your code, is that something is above your image and hence the click event is not passed to the UIButton sub-class (EGOImageButton).

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the method your selector is refered to contains  a sender of type UIButton

so like this     -(void)buttonTouched:(UIButton *)sender

Comment: Can't we put id instead of UIButton for the sender

Answer (score 0):

action:

```
@selector(buttonTouched:)
```

I think you don't need colon : here, remove it and try action: like this:

```
@selector(buttonTouched)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your `buttonTouched` method needs to have a return type of `IBAction` instead of `void`.